# A better way to splice out longs/shorts from byte array

Tags: c++, casting, short

So I'm constructing shorts/longs based on byte arrays here, and I wanted to avoid using `memcpy` to copy bytes into their own variable, and then assigning that variable to a `sockaddr_in` object.

Is there a better way to extract the `short` in the following statement?:

```
((sockaddr_in*)from)->sin_port = (*((unsigned short*)&buf[4]));
```

I did the whole pointer/dereference thing because, if my logic is correct, doing just an `(unsigned short)buf[4]` cast will only convert one byte; not both.

EDIT: Endianness is fine. I just want buf[4] and buf[5] to be together in one short in an easy way, other than having to use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question:

```
(*((unsigned short*)&buf[4]))
```

may not work, due to the following issues:

- [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
- [alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)
- [aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html)

`memcpy` is safe if you're confident about the endianness (if not, then you should combine with `ntohs` or `ntohl`).  A decent compiler should also optimize it away.

If you really want to avoid `memcpy`, then a safe, platform-independent way is something like the following (assuming that `buf` was originally populated from an external source, using standard network byte order):

```
((buf[n] << 8) | buf[n+1])
```

Of course, you should wrap that in a function (or a macro, if you must).

Comment: Endiannes is fine - I've already tested this (the `memcpy` solution was working, but I'm trying to optimize)

Comment: Could you expand on alignment/aliasing?

Comment: @Di-0xide: Alignment - it's possible that `&buf[4]` is not suitably-aligned to be read as a 16-bit quantity.  Aliasing - the compiler is free to make assumptions about how various objects will be accessed (aka "aliased") when performing optimizations; your original code would violate those assumptions.

Comment: Also, thanks for the links. "Dereferencing a cast of a variable from one type of pointer to a different type is usually in violation of the strict aliasing rule."

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper solution would under all circumstances be to use functions such as `ntohs` and `htons` (for `long` use [`ntohl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) and `htonl`).

```
((sockaddr_in*)from)->sin_port = htons(*((unsigned short*)&buf[4]));
```

Also keep in mind that depending on the source of your byte array you may run into additional Endianess issues.

Alignment can be another issue on some architectures (HP-RISC, SPARC). The functions `memcpy` and `memmove` usually don't have those issues. **And you shouldn't optimize prematurely!**

Comment: This may also suffer from alignment and aliasing issues.

Comment: `htons`/`ntohs`, etc. are just to fix endianness if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Di-0xide: indeed. Oli: I wrote that (not the aliasing issue, admittedly)

Answer (score 0):

you may use the ntohs macro to handle endianness conversion, htons means host-to-network order

```
((sockaddr_in*)from)->sin_port = htons(*((uint16_t*)&buf[4]));
```

Note that, however some architecture does not allow unaligned access, so you need to make sure it's aligned or you may need to fetch aligned bytes into temp variable and shuffle the bits accordingly.